# Problem installing statsmodels on Apple M1

Tags: python, statsmodels, apple-m1

I have trouble installing statsmodels on Apple M1. I have tried installing with a rosetta enabled terminal, and conda-forge, but still not able to get it installed.

I get a long error ending with the following:

```
                  clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
                  clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
                  clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
                  error: Command "clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -DNPY_INTERNAL_BUILD=1 -DHAVE_NPY_CONFIG_H=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DNO_ATLAS_INFO=3 -DHAVE_CBLAS -Ibuild/src.macosx-12.3-arm64-3.7/numpy/core/src/umath -Ibuild/src.macosx-12.3-arm64-3.7/numpy/core/src/npymath -Ibuild/src.macosx-12.3-arm64-3.7/numpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.macosx-12.3-arm64-3.7/numpy/core/include/numpy -Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/Users/amin-asdzdh/Developer/padfoot/.venv_padfoot/include -I/Users/amin-asdzdh/.pyenv/versions/3.7.13/include/python3.7m -Ibuild/src.macosx-12.3-arm64-3.7/numpy/core/src/common -Ibuild/src.macosx-12.3-arm64-3.7/numpy/core/src/npymath -Ibuild/src.macosx-12.3-arm64-3.7/numpy/core/src/common -Ibuild/src.macosx-12.3-arm64-3.7/numpy/core/src/npymath -c numpy/core/src/multiarray/alloc.c -o build/temp.macosx-12.3-arm64-3.7/numpy/core/src/multiarray/alloc.o -MMD -MF build/temp.macosx-12.3-arm64-3.7/numpy/core/src/multiarray/alloc.o.d -faltivec -I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers" failed with exit status 1
                  [end of output]
      
              note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
            error: legacy-install-failure
      
            × Encountered error while trying to install package.
            ╰─> numpy
      
            note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
            hint: See above for output from the failure.
            [end of output]
      
        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      error: subprocess-exited-with-error
      
      × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
      │ exit code: 1
      ╰─> See above for output.
      
      note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.
```

Comment: it needs to complie `C/C++` code but it seems on Apple M1 `"the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly"`. But I don't know how to set it.